# Admin page doesn't work in orgfree Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My admin page doesn't work when I host it on orgfree.com. It shows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /home/vhosts/mysite.orgfree.com/admin/admin.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /home/vhosts/mysite.orgfree.com/admin/admin.php(39): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'pass') #1 {main} thrown in /home/vhosts/mysite.orgfree.com/admin/admin.php on line 39

I checked on line 39 my code was

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

I hope someone would help me.

Comment: Your user and password are invalid for your MySQL host.

Comment: What should I do sir? I have to change it?

Comment: the user and password are provided by free web hosting, can I change it?

Comment: content of your $user variable should correspond to the permissions GRANted on the database.

Comment: Seems like you need some outside help, Stackoverflow isn't going to be a replacement for an experienced developer or administrator to help you with these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this msg say you not have the good name or good password try to go phpmyadmin and test your logs I think will be broke too

if you dont find your credentials reinstall you mysql and if you are on linux distrip the program ask you the pass for root if you are on window the default is root and pass is ''

good day